# How to get the first date of the week and last date of the week of month in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'll provide the month it should fetch the first week date and last week date in excel and it should not include weekends, Sat and Sun. Following example for your reference.

**Example**

*February*

```
February 5th - February 9th
February 12th - February 16th
February 19th- February 23rd
February 24th- February 29th
```

Comment: So you want to input the word "February" and output not only the 1st and last week, but 4 rows of data of the ***current*** year?

Comment: Also, your example suggests that you want the first and last *working* day of each week, but you didn't state that. Do you expect to exclude national holidays as well?

Comment: So where do 1-4 February belong to? (or at least 1 & 2, which are not weekend)

Comment: Your last week is off. 24th is a Saturday. IOt would become `February 25th- March 1st`, but that includes a day of March, which is unclear if that's accepted. Also do you need it to include 1`st`, 2`nd`, 3`rd`, n`th`? leaving that out makes it a lot simpler.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can use one of these formulas

```vb
=LET(startMonth,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),B1,1),
     firstMonday,startMonth-WEEKDAY(startMonth,3),
     allMondays,firstMonday+SEQUENCE(5,,0,7),
     allFridays,allMondays+4,
     FILTER(HSTACK(allMondays,allFridays),allMondays<=EOMONTH(startMonth,0)))
```

or for full weeks only:

```vb
=LET(startMonth,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),B1,1),
firstMonday,startMonth-WEEKDAY(startMonth,3),
allMondays,firstMonday+SEQUENCE(5,,0,7),
allFridays,allMondays+4,
FILTER(HSTACK(allMondays,allFridays),(allMondays>=startMonth)* (allFridays<=EOMONTH(startMonth,0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Please attach excel for my reference. Its doesn't work for me in excel

Comment: What is your Excel-version?

Comment: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2310 Build 16.0.16924.20054) 64-bit

Comment: Hmm - then it should work. What's your language? What is the error or what do you mean by "It doesn't work"? Maybe you have to update B1 for your months value?

Comment: If possible, could you please attach the excel in the answer, please

Comment: @VBasic2008 - you are right: it should be `allMondays+4` to retrieve the Fridays (headbang) - fixed it

Comment: And if `B1` would be text (like in the example) you could use `--(B1&-1)` for `startMonth`

Comment: @P.b Doesn't work for me (`#NUM!` error) with the default or local month name. Any ideas?

Comment: @VBasic2008 how about =DATEVALUE(1&B1)?

Comment: `=LET(s,DATEVALUE(1&B1),
     m,SEQUENCE(5,,s-(MOD(s-2,7)),7),
TOCOL(m/(MONTH(m)=MONTH(s)),2)+{0,4})` works for me

Comment: @P.b Yeah, `=MONTH(DATEVALUE(1&B1))` works for me.

Comment: Thumb up for `+{0,4}` instead of `HSTACK`

Answer (score 1):

### Work Weeks of Month

- The following is something in between Ike's solutions i.e. each Monday of a month starts a week of the same month i.e. even if it's the 31st, the week belongs to this month.

```
=LET(work_month,A2,work_days,5,wd_return,2,
    f,DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),work_month,1),
    n,MOD(8-WEEKDAY(f,wd_return),7),
    nf,f+n+SEQUENCE(5,,0,7),
    s,TOCOL(IFS(nf<=EOMONTH(f,0),nf),2),
    r,HSTACK(s,s+work_days-1),
    r)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

- Credits to **P.b** (see OP's comments) who figured out that you can retrieve the first of the month from the full or abbreviated month string using `DATEVALUE(1&A2)`.

```
=LET(month_string,A2,work_days,5,wd_return,2,
    f,DATEVALUE(1&month_string),
    n,MOD(8-WEEKDAY(f,wd_return),7),
    nf,f+n+SEQUENCE(5,,0,7),
    s,TOCOL(IFS(nf<=EOMONTH(f,0),nf),2),
    r,HSTACK(s,s+work_days-1),
    r)
```

- If you want to return each row in a single cell literally as you have posted, you could use (or improve on) the following:

```
=LET(month_string,A2,work_days,5,wd_return,2,
    th,LAMBDA(d,IFS(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(d,{1;21;31})),"st",
        ISNUMBER(XMATCH(d,{2;22})),"nd",
        ISNUMBER(XMATCH(d,{3;23})),"rd",TRUE,"th")),
    f,DATEVALUE(1&month_string),
    n,MOD(8-WEEKDAY(f,wd_return),7),
    nf,f+n+SEQUENCE(5,,0,7),
    s,TOCOL(IFS(nf<=EOMONTH(f,0),nf),2),
    d,DAY(s),
    ls,s+work_days-1,
    ld,DAY(ls),
    r,TEXT(s,"mmmm d")&th(d)&" - "&TEXT(ls,"mmmm d")&th(ld),
    r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Place these formulas to the defined cells:

C25: Input cell of the month number (in example = 2)

D25: `=MIN(IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(2024,$C$25,ROW(1:31)),2)=1,DATE(2024,$C$25,ROW(1:31))))`

D26: `=IF(MONTH(MAX(IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(2024;$C$25,ROW(1:31)),2)=1,DATE(2024,$C$25,ROW(1:31))))+5)=C25,MAX(IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(2024,$C$25,ROW(1:31)),2)=1,DATE(2024,$C$25,ROW(1:31)))),MAX(IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(2024,$C$25,ROW(1:31)),2)=1,DATE(2024,$C$25,ROW(1:31))))-7)`

E25: `=D25+5`

E26: `=D26+5`

The result:

[image]

Comment: please attach the excel for my reference

Comment: The minimal excel is determined by the used functions. This can be checked on Microsoft sites. There you can find a complete list for every function where they can be used.